# Splitting up Rows in SQL

Tags: c#, database, csv, sorting

I would like to know how I can split up some rows that I have in a database.
Currently I have it so that data is being sent to the database via C# and what I would like to be able to do is split this data up and send the data to another table

Example of data that I have

```
flats 
5342|namecode|Full Name|COMM|Technology & Commercial Division|CORPFIN|Corporate Finance Division|2018-03-05 09:27:34.433000000
```

I have removed the names for security reasons etc...

How would I be able to split this up into the fields and then send to another table?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit your question?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts its just a flat database with no relational tables as it will just be for this data

Comment: What are your column names and what sort of result are you looking for?

Comment: So a flat CSV, not a database? If so, SQL is irrelevant.

Comment: I mean it has all the columns and what its doing is so far is taking data from an excel doc whenever it is dragged into a folder then sending to sql and id like on the sql side so that its in the correct columns so like id, name code, full name etc

Comment: DIWOR, 
Earnercode, 
earnerNAME ,
DEPT_CODE ,
Nt_user_name, 
ActDate ,
Blank ,
Status ,
Office ,
Dept ,
Dated ,
ID

Comment: Split the string https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx